# Android PackageManager No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

When using the [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) to get a list of applications from the device, if i call `pm.getApplicationIcon(app);` and the application **does not** have an icon, the system will return the system default *[as it's supposed to do](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo))*, but i get this error output in my console:

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.google.android.gsf.login: Resource ID #0x0
```

Since i'm looping through all applications on the phone, this turns into some pretty bad spam that I'd like to avoid if possible.

**My Code**

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

for (ApplicationInfo app : pm.getInstalledApplications(0)) {
    long dataUsed = ((TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(app.uid) + TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(app.uid)) / 1000) / 1000;

    if ((int)dataUsed > 0) {
        String name = pm.getApplicationLabel(app).toString();
        Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(app);

        // Custom object
        DataUsageItem item = new DataUsageItem(name, icon, false, dataUsed, new int[]{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 });
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the `ApplicationInfo` for each should have an `icon` field which is the resource ID. Check if it's nonzero before calling `getApplicationIcon()`.

Comment: @MikeM. is there a way to still get the "Default android application icon" without using this method then? Because I'd still like that.

Comment: Umm, off the cuff, if that's zero, load `android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon` instead. Pretty sure that's the right ID.

Comment: @MikeM. seems to work! If you want to submit it as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Cool. Just FYI, I have double-checked the source code to make sure that's correct, and not only working "by accident". Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ApplicationInfo` for each will have an `icon` field that holds the resource ID for that drawable in the given package. Check that it's nonzero before calling `getApplicationIcon()`.

For those packages that do not have an icon – i.e., those whose `icon` field is zero – you can retrieve the system default icon with the `android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon` ID.